# How did Ravenna's mom end up with such insane powers?

Tags: character, snow-white-and-the-huntsman

In *Snow White and the Huntsman* (2012), I wonder, who was Ravenna's mother was and why she dies? It seems like with all that power, she should be in a better shape.

Comment: By "she should have been in better shape", do you mean Ravenna's mother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ravenna's mother was supposedly a sorceress, and brought that trait to Ravenna. I am guessing that Finn (Ravenna's brother) did not get that lucky. She probably got the insane powers, one, because she was taught sorcery, and two from her mother. She also could have gotten it from the potion she drank, given to her from her mother before she was taken. I believe Ravenna's mother died because back then, people feared sorcery. They took Ravenna and Finn, thinking the mothers loss of children would make her grow weaker.